# Pandas Apply lambda function null values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a column in two, but I know there are null values in my data.  Imagine this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['fruit: apple','vegetable: asparagus',None, 'fruit: pear'], columns = ['text'])

df

                   text
0          fruit: apple
1  vegetable: asparagus
2                   None
3           fruit: pear
```

I'd like to split this into multiple columns like so:

```
df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == None else x.split(': ')[0])
df['value'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == None else x.split(': ')[1])

print df

                   text        cat      value
0          fruit: apple      fruit      apple
1  vegetable: asparagus  vegetable  asparagus
2                  None    unknown    unknown
3           fruit: pear      fruit       pear
```

However, if I have the following df instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['fruit: apple','vegetable: asparagus',np.nan, 'fruit: pear'], columns = ['text'])
```

splitting results in the following error:

```
df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == np.nan else x.split(': ')[0])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-8e5bca809635> in <module>()
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(['fruit: apple','vegetable: asparagus',np.nan, 'fruit: pear'], columns = ['text'])
      2 #df.columns = ['col_name']
----> 3 df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == np.nan else x.split(': ')[0])
      4 df['value'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == np.nan else x.split(': ')[1])

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2158             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2159 
-> 2160         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2161         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2162             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62187)()

<ipython-input-159-8e5bca809635> in <lambda>(x)
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(['fruit: apple','vegetable: asparagus',np.nan, 'fruit: pear'], columns = ['text'])
      2 #df.columns = ['col_name']
----> 3 df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == np.nan else x.split(': ')[0])
      4 df['value'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == np.nan else x.split(': ')[1])

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**How do I do the same split with NaN values?**
Is there generally a better way to apply a split function that ignores null values?

Imagine this wasn't a string example, instead if I had the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,4,6,8,10,np.nan,12], columns = ['numerics'])
df['numerics'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else x/2.0)
```

I feel like Series.apply should almost take an argument that instructs it to skip null rows and just output them as nulls. I haven't found a better *generic* way to do transformations to a series without having to manually avoid nulls.

Comment: try `df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if pd.isnull(x) else x.split(': ')[0])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `apply` with a custom function you could use the `Series.str.extract` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# df = pd.DataFrame(['fruit: apple','vegetable: asparagus',None, 'fruit: pear'], 
#                   columns = ['text'])
df = pd.DataFrame(['fruit: apple','vegetable: asparagus',np.nan, 'fruit: pear'], 
                  columns = ['text'])
df[['cat', 'value']] = df['text'].str.extract(r'([^:]+):?(.*)', expand=True).fillna('unknown')
print(df)
```

yields

```
                   text        cat       value
0          fruit: apple      fruit       apple
1  vegetable: asparagus  vegetable   asparagus
2                   NaN    unknown     unknown
3           fruit: pear      fruit        pear
```

---

`apply` with a custom function is generally slower than equivalent code which makes use of vectorized methods such as `Series.str.extract`. Under the hood, `apply` (with an unvectorizable function) essentially calls the custom function in a Python `for-loop`.

---

Regarding the edited question: If you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,4,6,8,10,np.nan,12], columns = ['numerics'])
```

then use

```
In [207]: df['numerics']/2
Out[207]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    NaN
6    6.0
Name: numerics, dtype: float64
```

instead of

```
df['numerics'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else x/2.0)
```

Again, vectorized arithmetic beats `apply` with a custom function:

```
In [210]: df = pd.concat([df]*100, ignore_index=True)

In [211]: %timeit df['numerics']/2
10000 loops, best of 3: 93.8 µs per loop

In [212]: %timeit df['numerics'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else x/2.0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 836 µs per loop
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? It works with version 0.18.0.

Comment: 17.0, but this is a minor point - updating question to reflect.

Comment: @flyingmeatball, it works. Here is a bit more complicated test case: `df = pd.DataFrame(['', 'fruit: apple',None,'vegetable: asparagus',np.nan, 'fruit: pear'], columns = ['text'])`

Comment: @MaxU I believe the simple cases work, I'm less worried about the minor syntax for this example.  I'm more interested in trying to find a good way to skip nulls in an apply statement.  I find myself needing to do that relatively frequently.

Comment: @unutbu thanks - I'm beginning to get the sense that the answer to my underlying question is that there isn't a good way to do a vanilla apply and skip nulls - it depends on the individual column.  My edited df was more an example of a non-text manipulation, I wouldn't actually use apply in that instance, just wanted to find a case that I couldn't apply a regular expression.  Appreciate the help.